# How to enable CDN on Atlassian Confluence Server?

Tags: confluence

I would like to use Atlassian Confluence Server with CloudFront CDN, but there is no documentation explaining how to configure this within Confluence. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems as though this feature is undocumented within Confluence, but here are the steps;

1) Enable dark feature `confluence.fixed.cdn.enabled` via `<confluence_url_here>/admin/darkfeatures.action`

Or you can enable dark feature in `setenv.sh` using;

`-Datlassian.darkfeature.confluence.fixed.cdn.enabled=true`

2) Edit `setenv.sh` and add:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dconfluence.fixed.cdn.prefix=https://YOURCDNGOESHERE/ ${CATALINA_OPTS}"
```

Comment: Nice finding :-)